# Issue while writing cells in excel file using apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am facing issue while writing the data to excel file.
I am using apache POI 4.1.2 version library.
Below is the sample code.

```
    try {
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(EXCEL_FILE_PATH);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception While writing excel file " + e.getMessage());
    }

    Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("FileCompare");

    Row row = sheet.createRow(0);

    Cell cellfilename = row.createCell(0);
    cellfilename.setCellValue("File Name");

    Cell cellfilename1 = row.createCell(1);
    cellfilename1.setCellValue("Difference in File 1");

    Cell cellfilenam2 = row.createCell(2);
    cellfilenam2.setCellValue("Difference in File 2");

    for (int diffcol = 1; diffcol < 3; diffcol++) {
        for (int i = 1; i < 57; i++) {

            Row rows = sheet.createRow(i);
            // System.out.println("Difference Coln number " + diffcol);
            Cell diffcell = rows.createCell(diffcol);
            diffcell.setCellValue("abacds");

            /*
             * Cell diffcell2 = row.createCell(2); diffcell2.setCellValue("abacds");
             */

        }
        
    }


    try {
        workbook.write(outputStream);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        workbook.close();
    }
```

In this only last column cells is getting saved in excel file , previous cells are kept as blank.
Kindly help and let me know if I am doing something wrong?

[image: Please find attached snippet for more reference]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the actual api but I think you inner loop should create columns and your outer one should create rows like this

```
  for (int row=1:row<57;row++)
  {
     Row rows = sheet.createRow(row);
     for (int diffCol = 1; diffCol < 3; difCol++) 
     {
        Cell diffcell = rows.createCell(diffcol);
        diffcell.setCellValue("abacds");
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that inside your loop you're always using `sheet.createRow(i)` to retrieve the row you need, **but** as [the docs](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#createRow-int-) says (docs that are written not so clear, actually) this method is always **recreating a brand new & empty row, deleting the existing one** (if a row at that i-position was already present).

It means that each iteration of yuor loop is actually deleting previous rows creating brand new rows: at the end only rows created by the last iteration are surviving!

To solve you're problem, use `sheet.createRow(i)` *only one time* in order to create the row at i-position and then only use [`sheet.getRow(i)`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#getRow-int-) to retreive it.

So replace (in your code) the following *wrong* line

```
Row rows = sheet.createRow(i);
```

with the following code

```
Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
if (row == null) row = sheet.createRow(i);
```

where new row is created only if it does not already exist!

And you're done, it works like a charm!